# How to create a view hierarchy programmatically without using a nib?

Tags: iphone

How to create a view hierarchy programmatically without using a nib ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole view hierarchy can be constructed using successive `UIView` construction and `-addSubview:` methods.

For instance, to create an input form one may use

```
UIView* rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
// apply style to rootView
[window addSubview:rootView];
[rootView release];

UILabel* inputLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
// apply style to label
[rootView addSubview:inputLabel];
[inputLabel release];

UITextField* inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
// apply style to text field
[rootView addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

and so on.